# Unable to scrape the value of a certain key from a static webpage using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the value of this key `data-component-props` from this [webpage](https://www.udemy.com/) using the requests module in combination with BeautifulSoup library. The content I wish to grab from that page seems to be static, as it is available in [page source](https://img.incoherency.co.uk/4364).

However, when I try something like the following, the script raises `TypeError`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.udemy.com/"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    container = soup.select_one("[class='ud-component--logged-out-home--logged-out-home']")['data-component-props']
    print(container)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for specifying `headers` here in my opinion, just request without update - Behavior seems to be with the `user-agent`, if you skip it, your script is also working:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.udemy.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

json.loads(soup.select_one("[class='ud-component--logged-out-home--logged-out-home']").get('data-component-props'))
```

**In addition:**

It seems that when you come with a known browser in the `user-agent`, the website does some extra checks, availability of `JavaScript`,... that fail with the `requests` module